# Venti Calendar URL

Tags: events, plugin-ventievents

I have contacted support and looked in the usual places, it's the weekend so might not be till Monday that I hear back from support.

Issue is that I cannot seem to get the URL right when displaying a summary of events page. I am using {{ event.url }}. I want it to go to http://domain.com/**events**/name-of-event/2017-04-27 but instead it is http://domain.com/**event**/name-of-event/2017-04-27.  How can I get it to be /events/ not /event/?

If anyone uses Venti and knows why this is please let me know.  I am going to keep on digging in the meantime. Thanks.

Comment: I know the default is /event/ I want to change the default to /events/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After speaking with support, it's hardwired that way to have /event so I changed my structure to event, not the end of the world.  I do want to say I am actively evaluating this plugin and support was emailing me back and forth on Friday night.  So I appreciated their after hours response.